# How do i anchor subviews of a UIScrollView like the URL bar in mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I want to do something similar to how mobile safari keeps its URL bar anchored at the top of the screen while a page is loading unless you scroll past the top, in which case it scrolls down with the rest of the content.

I, however, want the opposite to happen; I want specific subviews to scroll off the screen if I scroll down, but if I scroll to the top I want the subviews to stay anchored at the top of the screen while the rest of the content continues to scroll down.  I suppose I could do some trickery with the view hierarchy where the subviews change their superview when we scroll to the top, but I'm wondering if there are any other more elegant solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very late answer to my own question, but I figured i'd reveal how I was able to do this.

I subclassed UIScrollView and implemented the layoutSubviews method, which is called every time the scroll position changes. Here, all you need to do is identify which view you want to anchor and do something like this:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews {
  [super layoutSubviews];

  CGFloat x = 0.0f;
  CGFloat y = MIN(self.contentOffset.y,0.0f);

  anchorview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,anchorview.frame.size.width,anchorview.frame.size.height);
}
```

If you want the anchored view to stay at the top if you scroll past the top (instead of remaining in the same position relative to the scrollview), then this will do just that, since the content offset's y coordinate will be less than zero when you scroll beyond the very top of the view.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView section headers already do this in plain tables, you could leverage that behavior.

Comment: those behave in the opposite way that i want though; i want the view to anchor itself when i scroll past the top and scroll with the content otherwise, not the other way around as table view headers work in plain tables; also i'd like it to work on either style of table view.